# Determine if form was submitted through JS or by user click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, http

I have a problem that I should determine whenever form is sended through JS `submit` function or by user click on `submit` button (or opening link in another tab).

The best I found for now is use `ajax` form submission with custom header:

```
var $form = $('form#searchForm');
$.submit($form, { headers: { 'X-Session-Request': true } }).done('???');
```

where `$.submit` is my wrapper over `$.ajax` for forms.

But here is a problem that I don't know how to emulate submission response. I sended a form with headers, and it's fine on this step, but then server returns HTML with JS, and I should show this HTML and execute script. I can't just reload a page, becuase it will cause a `GET` request without my custom header to be sended and thus all this stuff becomes needless.

How can I do it?

Comment: Probably the best thing is to use a separate `GET` header.

Comment: I'm looking now on 1-second expiration cookies, but it still looks hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I actially solve it with 1-second cookie. Not very elegant, but still working:

```
function submitFormInCurrentSession() {
    addCookie('XSessionCookie', true, 1000);
    $('form#searchForm').submit();
}
```

where addCookie (typescript):

```
function addCookie(name: string, value: any, expirationMs: number) {
    const date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + expirationMs);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${date.toUTCString()}; path=/`;
}
```